# How to correctly set a date using datepicker?

Tags: javascript, php, html, datepicker, mdbootstrap

I have 3 pages:

```
registration
all values
detail page
```

Once I register all the values ​​on the registration page, and go to the page where I see all my results, obviously as I set I get the date of a value, so far nothing strange, when I then go to the information page of the product, where I can change the values ​​of the product, through a while loop I get out all the information of that product.

Here the problem begins, I have information about my product that is:

```
first name
height
weight
Expiration date
```

example:

```
Jar
20cm
1kg
05/20/2019
```

Summarizing everything, I have these values ​​and I'm on the information page of the individual product, this page allows me to be able to modify the values ​​of the product.

If I change only the name, not touching the date, automatically the date from the correct format set during registration, changes me in the db in:00/00/0000

Every time I want to change a value within the single product I have to select the date again even if it is perfectly correct and inserted in the db, visible from the while loop, I don't understand why

#### Code for datepicker:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="md-form">
         <input name="scadenza_richiesta"  value="<?php echo formato_data_scad_rich($row['scadenza_richiesta']) ;?>"  type="text" id="scadenza_richiesta" class="form-control datepicker">                                   
        <label for="Form-email1" >Scadenza Richiesta</label>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#scadenza_richiesta').pickadate({
        format: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
        formatSubmit: 'yyyy/mm/dd',
        hiddenPrefix: 'prefix__',
        hiddenSuffix: '__suffix',
        min : true,
        });
    </script>  
</div>
```

image before the first registration about the product:
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OEbQP.png)

Update code:

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$id = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['ID_Richiesta']);
$titolo_richiesta = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['titolo_richiesta']);
$dettagli_richiesta = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['dettagli_richiesta']);
$scadenza_richiesta = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['scadenza_richiesta']);
$token_richiesta = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['token_richiesta']);
$categoria_richiesta = $connessione->real_escape_string($_POST['categoria_richiesta']);

$connessione->query("UPDATE richieste SET
categoria_richiesta='$categoria_richiesta',
titolo_richiesta='$titolo_richiesta',
dettagli_richiesta='$dettagli_richiesta',
scadenza_richiesta='$scadenza_richiesta',
token_richiesta='$token_richiesta'
WHERE ID_Richiesta ='$id'");

header("Location: richieste.php?ed_rich=Y");
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you show us the script that is being used to update the information?
Also, is the date saved in database "correctly" at first?

Comment: @Andreas update my question

Comment: Can you also answer my second question? Is the date stored correctly at first? Also, how is your date field in database called?

Comment: @Andreas Of course, yes, the date is memorized perfectly in the first step, that is the product registration date, and is shown perfectly on the page where all the products are present, and perfectly on the information page of the single product the field name is scadenza_richiesta

Comment: Ok, thanks for clarification. One more question: how is the date set during the registration? Is it automatically set by database on a new entry?

Comment: @Andreas It is recorded in the same item, since when I find myself on the product info page I access it by sending the id and I take out all the results with the while doing the $ _GET of the id

Comment: Yes, but how is it recorded in the first place? So what is the code for inserting into the database?

Comment: @Andreas same mode to update, if statement set a variables and changed the QUERY, with a form

Comment: You cannot insert new values in a database with an update statement. There must be something like `INSERT into richieste` ..

Comment: @Andreas certainly not, in fact in the registration page there is the INSERT INTO query, in the single detail information page there is a SELECT * FROM WHERE $ _GET and an update WHERE $ _POST ['id], taken from the $ _GET of the select

Comment: Ok. So can you show the entire INSERT INTO statement?

Comment: @Andreas is the same as the question but change the query from UPDATE to INSERT INTO, I don't understand your question, what could give the abnormal behavior described in the question?

Comment: I assume that in your update statement there is a problem with "date value", which does not have the needed format. If you are trying to update the value in the database with a not compatible string you get the result with the "00/00/0000". 
To find out what value there actually is, you could e.g. dump the $_POST var or echo out the single date value.